# shorter way to change data type of scalars and numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Can this function be written shorter? I end up doing this a lot in my code

```
def smartInt(x):
  if (type(x) == np.ndarray):
    return x.astype(int)
  else:
    return int(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with numpy scalars (e.g. `np.int_` instead of `int`, then you can do

```
np.asanyarray(x, int)[()]
```

or even

```
np.int_(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't shorter in terms of number of lines, but `try` / `except` may be more efficient than explicit type checking:

```
def smartInt(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except TypeError:
        return x.astype(int)
```

If an array is the more likely input:

```
def smartInt(x):
    try:
        return x.astype(int)
    except AttributeError:
        return int(x)
```